# how to pass a list to database and retrieve data in one go instead of using foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects,I need to fetch the data by passing them to db using LINQ,i can wrap them inside a forEach but thats not good because im hitting the database multiple times:

my object  is a class,call it incomingTransactions,consist of two fields :

```
    public string QuoteId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PaymentOptionId { get; set; } = default!;
```

Transactions is a table in DB and its entities are:

```
    public string QID{ get; set; } = default!;
    public string PaymentOptionId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Status{ get; set; } = default!;
    public string Name{ get; set; } = default!;
    public string FamilyName{ get; set; } = default!;
```

I need to fetch the data by the list, set the status as "done" and store them back to db.

```
 public async Task<bool> StoreConvertesCurrenciesAsync(List<incomingTransactions> listOfdata)
    {



           var result= await dbContext.Transactions.Select(new ModelEntity

            {
                Status = TransactionStatus.IsConverted.ToString()
                
            }).Where(x => listOfdata.Contains(x.QID) && listOfdata.Contains(x.PaymentOptionId));

        }
```

if i do the above thing i get the error :The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable, Func<TSource, int, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly,the error is under Select

Comment: I am puzzled - your "list" appears to be two `string` variables and your code has a `List<myList>` which isn't used... please update your question to be understandable.

Comment: @NetMage updated my question,sorry if it was not clear,my bad

Comment: `Select` expects Lambda, not just objet. `.Select(x => new ModelEntity ...`

Comment: should be as lyambda Select(s=> new ModelEntity